# loop over paired files in a bash script and create one txt file per sample

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have some `paired files` (`R1` and `R2` in names show they are paired) as follows:

```
sample1_R1.fastq
sample1_R2.fastq
sample2_R1.fastq
sample2_R2.fastq
sample3_R1.fastq
sample3_R2.fastq
```

I am trying to loop over the files and run the following command:

```
motus profile -f sample1_R1.fastq -r sample1_R2.fastq -t 4 > taxon1.txt
```

the expected output would be one `txt` file per sample.
to do so I made the following short bash script but it does not return the expected output. where is the problem in the below script?

```
location = PWD

for file in location:
do

  fastq1=$location/${file}_R1.fastq

  fastq2=$location/${file}_R2.fastq

  motus profile -f fastq1 -r fastq2 -t 4 > "${file}".txt
```

Comment: run your code through shellcheck

Comment: @jared_mamrot As file names could contain other `R1` sub-strings, `"${file%R1.fastq}R2.fastq"` is maybe safer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, where is the problem.

`for file in location`
will go through all files in the given folder, hence `*_R1.fastq` and `*_R2.fastq`.

In combination with `${file}_R1.fastq` this will lead to `sample1_R1.fastq_R1.fastq` and `sample1_R1.fastq_R2.fastq`.

Hence you have to filter the files you are working on.

Also `PWD` should be `$PWD` or the actual path.

@jared_mamrot wrote a good comment using only `for file in *_R1.fastq` in the current directory.

He then uses `"${file/R1/R2}"` to replace the `R1` in the filename with `R2` and finally extracts the leading part with `"${file%%_*}"`

You don't have to write it as short as he does, but this should give you the idea to understand the problems in the code and how to solve them.

---

Leading to

```
#! /bin/bash

for file in "$PWD"/*_R1.fastq
do
    fastq1=$file
    fastq2=${file/R1/R2}
    motus profile -f "$fastq1" -r "$fastq2" -t 4 > "text_${file%%_*}.txt"
done
```

Comment: @jhnc Thanks <3
Was in a hurry and wanted to have this finished before rushing out

Comment: @jhnc not according to shellcheck

Comment: I know that colon shouldn't be used that way ^^.
Edit is already on the way, but shellcheck still didn't found it.
So as I trusted shellcheck, I didn't notice it. Thank you by the way

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

for r1 in sample*_R1.fastq; do
    base=${r1%_R1.fastq}
    r2=${base}_R2.fastq
    [[ -f $r2 ]] || continue
    num=${base#sample}
    motus profile -f "$r1" -r "$r2" -t 4 > "taxon${num}.txt"
done
```

- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${r1%_R1.fastq}` and `${base#sample}`.

Comment: This might solve the problem, but doesn't answer OPs question.